# Using only the rules of inference to derive a conditional statement.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this question: P → ¬¬Q ⊢ ¬Q → ¬P
I have these steps for proof:

1. (1) P → ¬¬Q        Premise
2. (2) ¬Q             Premise

1,2. (3) ¬P           (1,2 Modus Tollens)

1. (4) ¬Q → ¬P        (2,3 CP)

Is this correct or do I need to do a double negation at some point?
The only applicable rules we're allowed to use are modus tollens, modus ponuns, double negation, and CP.

Comment: To be strict when applying *modus tollens*, maybe add a line of $\neg \neg \neg Q$ between (2) and (3).

Comment: not familiar with this notation, but on the left I'd do double negation first. Then modus tollens on the right, then I'd think you were done.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.